# update field of array object inside nested object

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have following db collection of users.

```
[{
name : "abc",
obj:{ id : 123 , arr[{fid:"a123",field:"0"},{fid:"b123",field:"0"}]}
},
{
name : "pqr",
obj:{ id : 456 , arr[{fid:"a456",field:"0"},{fid:"b456",field:"0"}]}

}]
```

I want to update field value of fid : b456 to 1 in mongodb.
How to write query for same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $

```
db.users.update({obj.arr.fid:"b456"},{$set: {"obj.arr.$.field":"1"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
db.users.update({"obj.arr.fid": b456 }, {$set: { "obj.arr.$.fid": 1 }})
```

> The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something?
Maybe this can help you:

```
db.users.update({name:"pqr"},{$set: {"obj.arr[1].fid":"1"}})
```

For more info take a look here [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)